# Как перегрузить оператор >> на с++?

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс class Stroka { private: char* str; int length; };

нужно сделать перегрузку >>, чтобы можно было из консоли вводить поля класса . строку вводить.
 Я делал вот так, но выдавало ошибку istream& operator>>(istream& is, Stroka& str) //оператор для ввода в поток { is >> *str.str; return is; }

Comment: А выделить память, куда читать?...

Comment: в каком плане ?

Answer (score 2):

Как верно указали в комментарии память под строку не выделяется, а отсюда и вылетает что-нибудь типа Access violation writing location %какой-нибудь адрес%.

`char*` это не строка ни разу, это - **указатель** на память в куче. Для того, чтобы этот указатель "стал" строкой надо выделить в куче память и записать адрес начала выделенного фрагмента память в этот указатель.

Можно примерно так решить:

```cpp
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Stroka& str)
{
    //
    // Ввожу строчку в буфер
    //

    std::string buffer;
    is >> buffer;

    str.length = static_cast<int>(buffer.size())

    //
    // Выделяю память и копирую данные
    //

    str.str = new char[str.length]; //  <----- вот это важно
    memcpy(str.str, buffer.c_str(), str.length);

    return is;
}
```

Кроме того, теперь для данной структуры надо написать деструктор - память то надо где-то очищать. А ещё надо написать много чего дополнительно во избежание неприятностей:

```cpp
class Stroka 
{ 
public:
    // Конструктор нужен для инициализации
    // полей класса во избежание освобождения
    // невыделенной памяти
    Stroka()
        : str(nullptr)
        , length(0)
    { }

    // В деструкторе освобождаем память
    ~Stroka() 
    { 
        if (str) 
        {
            delete[] str;
            str = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Подумаем о копировании. Самое простое - запретить (я так и сделаю),
    // но по-хорошему надо в другом объекте освободить память, выделить под
    // новую строчку, скопировать туда текущую и т.д.
    Stroka(const Stroka&) = delete;
    Stroka& operator=(const Stroka&) = delete;

    // Начиная с С++11 аналогично стоит поступать и с перемещением.
    // Есть исключения, но для этого пока рано. По мере изучения языка освоишь :)
    Stroka(Stroka&&) = delete;
    Stroka& operator=(Stroka&&) = delete;

    // Оператор должен иметь доступ к полям класса
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Stroka& str);
private: 
    char* str; 
    int length; // Лучше size_t, a не int
};
```

Короче просто так тут не отделаться :)

Comment: Создавать временную строку - жульничество. :)